# How to set root element as List in XML JAVA

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, ibm-cloud

I need a way to create the below object in java spring-boot controller. it like `List<Object>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oauth-revocation>
    <token type="access">AAETb2F1dGgtcmV2b2tlLWN1c3RvbfZaRlVbnPSc1...</token>
    <token type="refresh">fZaRlVbnPSc1UGTjCRdq4mPbOosD2+aZIKbJ6bTeW...</token>
    <resource-owner client-id="760d75a2-44b1-4485-8c6f-0d264fcf7398">laura</resource-owner>
    <resource-owner client-id="760d75a2-44b1-4485-8c6f-0d264fcf7398">emily</resource-owner>
</oauth-revocation>
```

Issue is i don't know way to set root element as oauth-revocation for the list.

Answer (score 2):

Implement that as a POJO with 2 `List` fields, not as a `List<Object>`:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "oauth-revocation")
public class OauthRevocation {
    @XmlElement(name = "token")
    private List<Token> tokens;
    @XmlElement(name = "resource-owner")
    private List<ResourceOwner> resourceOwners;
}

public class Token {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    private String type;
    @XmlValue
    private String value;
}

public class ResourceOwner {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "client-id")
    private String clientId;
    @XmlValue
    private String name;
}
```

Add constructors and other standard methods as needed.

*Test*

```java
OauthRevocation root = new OauthRevocation(Arrays.asList(
        new Token("access", "AAETb2F1dGgtcmV2b2tlLWN1c3RvbfZaRlVbnPSc1..."),
        new Token("refresh", "fZaRlVbnPSc1UGTjCRdq4mPbOosD2+aZIKbJ6bTeW...")
    ), Arrays.asList(
        new ResourceOwner("760d75a2-44b1-4485-8c6f-0d264fcf7398", "laura"),
        new ResourceOwner("760d75a2-44b1-4485-8c6f-0d264fcf7398", "emily")
    ));

Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(OauthRevocation.class).createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
```

*Output*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<oauth-revocation>
    <token type="access">AAETb2F1dGgtcmV2b2tlLWN1c3RvbfZaRlVbnPSc1...</token>
    <token type="refresh">fZaRlVbnPSc1UGTjCRdq4mPbOosD2+aZIKbJ6bTeW...</token>
    <resource-owner client-id="760d75a2-44b1-4485-8c6f-0d264fcf7398">laura</resource-owner>
    <resource-owner client-id="760d75a2-44b1-4485-8c6f-0d264fcf7398">emily</resource-owner>
</oauth-revocation>
```